# How to use logic:iterate to generate list of hyperlinks in Struts?

Tags: javascript, java, struts1

I need to generate a list of email addresses using logic:iterate tags, my problem is that these generated email list should be links to their profile.

My code to generate the list is:

```
<logic:iterate id="internalEmailList" name="confirm_form" property="emailList" indexId="emailCount">

<td class="left"><bean:write name="internalEmailList" property="email"/></td>

</logic:iterate>
```

I need to make this list link to their profiles using JS with the respective email as the parameter to view their profile.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

You can have smth like this below, in addition in Java Script you should define a function profile with one parameter to display the profile based on email

%>)">